# set ng-Model to string on number input

Tags: angularjs

I have a number input that I would like to set the `ngModel` dynamically based on values in an array

```
<input type="number" ng-model="{{$scope. + denom.label}}" tabindex="1" />
```

I realize I can't put the `{{ }}` in the ng-model and they aren't necessary because already in an angular controller, however,

```
<input type="number" ng-model="$scope. + denom.label" tabindex="1" />
```

doesn't work either.  `denom.label` is a string but `"$scope." + denom.label'` would evaluate to a number.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="denom.label" tabindex="1" />
```

The above doesn't work either. `denom.label` evaluates as a string and the error says that expects the ngModel to be a number. I need it to evaluate to `$scope.pennies` for example

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below markup..

**Markup**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="this[denom.label]"/>
```

Comment: perfect, did exactly as intende

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the code below to make this work.

```
<input type="number" ng-model="denom.label" tabindex="1" />
```

Comment: I've tried that an it errors saying that it expects denom.label to be a number denom.label value would be something like "pennies". I'd need $scope.pennies there